# How to create a POST with form-data for an API endpoint that accepts a list of files inside a list of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, form-data

I am trying to create a request in postman to upload files to a dotnet core endpoint that expects the following shape:

```
public class MyDto
{
   public DateTime Time { get; set; }
   public List<Logs> Files { get; set; } = null!;
   public class Logs
   {
       public ServiceEnum Service { get; set; }
       public List<IFormFile> LogFiles { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Function signature of action:

```
[HttpPost("{​id}​/log")]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveLogs([FromRoute] string id, [FromForm] MyDto myDto)
```

My postman request looks like this:
[image: Screen shot of postman setup with attempted api request]

When I try debugging this I can see that `myDto.Files[0].Service` is set yet, `myDto.Files[0].LogFiles` in null.

I was expecting that uploading multiple files would be mapped into `myDto.Files[0].LogFiles` from the request. I might be formatting the keys in the request wrong but I have tried multiple different key formats at this point.

Comment: Try removing the brackets around `[files]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I test with other simple and complex types, they can use square brackets and post successfully(Except for `IFormFile`). Maybe it is by design in Postman. Any way, no matter what type it is. You can always post like `xx.xx.xx`.

Change your post data like below:

[image]